# Write image on sd-card whithout recreate partitions

Tags: linux-mint, disk-image

Balena-etcher recreate partitions during write process, but I want write an image on SD-CARD with preconfigured partitions. How can I do?

Comment: Sorry, i not undersand your question

Comment: Does the image have a partition table?

Comment: @muru yes......

Comment: If it is an image of a drive, Etcher and other cloning tools will restore a system (on another drive of at least the same size as the original drive) with the same partition table and file systems as on the original drive. If you want some other partition table than in the image, you have to do that manually, and it might be complicated.

Comment: manually it's easy but the time is long

Comment: Please describe with more details what you have and what you want. (Edit the original question for this purpose.)

Comment: i want simply create before my partition table and after write the image with the unaltered partition created by me

Comment: What kind of image is it? (Created by you or by someone else, an iso file or some other kind of image, an image of one partition or of a drive, is there some boot structure, ...)

Comment: is an .sdimg downloaded from internet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105690/discussion-between-sudodus-and-riccardo-la-marca).